# python for loop and if not working properly

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have below code and it seems not working properly.

```
cylinderCount = [8,5,5,8]
engineCount = 4

for no in range(engineCount):
    for i in range(cylinderCount[no]):
       engineNo = str(no+1)

    if cylinderCount == 8:
       col = ["GA022"+str(i) + '_0'+str(engineNo) for i in range(20, cylinderCount[no]*10+11,10)] + ['GA02291'+'_0'+str(engineNo)]
    else:
       col = ["GA022"+str(i) + '_0'+str(engineNo) for i in range(20, cylinderCount[no]*10+11,10)]
```

The col should be

```
GA02220_04,GA02230_04,GA02240_04,GA02250_04,GA02260_04,GA02270_04,GA02280_04,GA02290_04,GA02291_04
```

but some how I only get

```
GA02220_04,GA02230_04,GA02240_04,GA02250_04,GA02260_04,GA02270_04,GA02280_04,GA02290_04
```

Can someone please tell me what I not getting GA02291_04?

Comment: You have `if cylinderCount == 8`. When do you expect `[8,5,5,8]` ever to be the same value as `8`?

Comment: I have assigned engine count as 4 so cylinder count should be 8.

Comment: `cylinderCount` is defined as `[8,5,5,8]` and never changes.

Answer (score 1):

you defined `cylinderCount` as a list, and then try to compare with a number, try changing.

```
...
if cylinderCount == 8:
....
```

to

```
...
if cylinderCount[no] == 8:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is big hard to digest, since you assign `col` but don't use it. This does the exact same thing as your code, but then cleaned-up and more DRY. Small assumption since your indentation is a bit off.

```py
cylinderCount = [8, 5, 5, 8]
engineCount = 4

rows = []
for engineno_int, cylinders in enumerate(cylinderCount):
    engineNo = str(engineno_int + 1)

    for i in range(cylinders):

        col = [f"GA022{i}_0{engineNo}" for i in range(20, cylinders * 10 + 11, 10)]
        if cylinders == 8:
            col += [f"GA02291_0{engineNo}"]
        rows.append(col)
```

Printing instead of append the col result in this:

```py
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare `cylinderCount` with `8`. Since `cylinderCount` is defined as `[8,5,5,8]` this will never be true. Maybe you meant `cylinderCount[no]`. In this case the program is overcomplicated and could be written as :

```
cylinders = [8, 5, 5, 8]
for no, cylinder in enumerate(cylinders, start=1):
    col = [f'GA022{i}_0{no}' for i in range(20, cylinder * 10 + 11, 10)]
    if cylinder == 8:
        col += [f'GA02291_0{no}']
    print(col)
```

With the result:

```
['GA02220_01', 'GA02230_01', 'GA02240_01', 'GA02250_01', 'GA02260_01', 'GA02270_01', 'GA02280_01', 'GA02290_01', 'GA02291_01']
['GA02220_02', 'GA02230_02', 'GA02240_02', 'GA02250_02', 'GA02260_02']
['GA02220_03', 'GA02230_03', 'GA02240_03', 'GA02250_03', 'GA02260_03']
['GA02220_04', 'GA02230_04', 'GA02240_04', 'GA02250_04', 'GA02260_04', 'GA02270_04', 'GA02280_04', 'GA02290_04', 'GA02291_04']
```